# Dynamically created dropdown menu isn't opening

Tags: javascript, html, css, semantic-ui

I created dropdown dynamically using javascript but when I tried opening the dropdown menu, it doesn't open at all.

This is how I created the dropdown dynamically:

```
$('#contentdiv').append("<div class='ui fluid selection dropdown'><input type='hidden' name='user'/><i class='dropdown icon'></i><div class='default text'>Select Friend/Follower</div><div class='menu' id='menu'>");
                    for(var k=0;k<fflist.length;k++)
                    {
                        $('#menu').append("<div class='item' data-value='"+fflist[k]+"'>"+fflist[k]+"</div>");
                    }
                    $('#contentdiv').append("</div></div>");
```

Web console show the element as this, I can't find any problem:

```
<div class="ui fluid selection dropdown">
<input type="hidden" name="user">
<i class="dropdown icon"></i>
<div class="default text">Select Friend/Follower</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu">
<div class="item" data-value="DivyanshuGaur16">DivyanshuGaur16</div>
<div class="item" data-value="akshaykumar">akshaykumar</div>
<div class="item" data-value="aamir_khan">aamir_khan</div>
<div class="item" data-value="SrBachchan">SrBachchan</div>
<div class="item" data-value="UncleOBEY">UncleOBEY</div>
<div class="item" data-value="Waakye_Orgasm">Waakye_Orgasm</div>
<div class="item" data-value="Iamdbeatz">Iamdbeatz</div>
<div class="item" data-value="KwameUltd">KwameUltd</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to create dropdown without select and option tag?

Comment: brother, it's semantic UI...

Comment: Problem has been solved, after creation, this needs a JavaScript code to initialize the dropdown... I forgot adding that